# php подружить с asterisk

Tags: php, асинхронность, asterisk

Появилась задача выводить оператору на web-интерфейс информацию о входящих звонках (соответственно сразу же искать клиента в БД). Покурив интернет, остановился на **WebSocket** сервере (cboden/ratchet) со связкой с **ARI** (greenfieldtech-nirs/phpari).

1. Стоит ли реализовывать всё это на чистом php?
2. Как поместить в один **EventLoop** сервер и ari клиент? Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, когда нужно организовывать два и более взаимодействующих потока на php
3. Не упадёт ли php работая непрерывно работая в потоке (слышал с этим пока всё плохо)?
4. А может забить на пункты выше и написать всё на java или python?

Comment: Зачем вебсокет? В своем проекте я использовал AMI. Интерфейс коммуникации стырил из проектов asternic и fop.

Comment: @gecube, asternic стремная вещь. Смотрел как там риал-тайм организован ajax + php общающийся с базой asteriska. Зло в чистом виде. Вебсокеты для того, чтобы сервер мог сам отправлять информацию, а не дергать ajax`ом каждую секунду скрипт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ariClient = new BasicStasisApplication('test');

$app = new Ratchet\App('localhost', 8080, '127.0.0.1', $ariClient->loop);
```

В общем нужно было взять `EventLoop` из ari и отдать его в ratchet. Благо последний поддерживает такую вещь.

П.С. В последствии было решено отказаться от [ARI](https://habrahabr.ru/post/225007/) и перейти на [AMI](http://www.pbxware.ru/wiki/asterisk_managment_interface_ami/) из **marcelog/pami**.

Comment: если вы добавите ссылки на ARI и AMI, чтобы будущим поколениям не пришлось гуглить, я заплюсую

Comment: @strangeqargo, ну кое-какие ссылки добавил...

Answer (score 1):

1 и 3) Нет, PHP не упадет, если в расширениях, которые вы используете, не будет утечек, что маловероятно.

4) пишите на чем угодно, если вы уверены, что в конторе где вы работаете смогут поддерживать ваш код, после того как вы свалите на другую работу.

я более чем уверен, что в интернете миллион рецептов на тему работы с астериском через php, и более чем уверен, что вебсокет вам для этих всех задач не особо нужен, а если нужен, и у вас  хайлоад биг дата коллцентр саппорт, то посоветуйтесь с начальством/коллегами на каком языке писать, раз нет регламента.

P.S. хотя, возможно ратчет (посмотрел на него) и хорошая идея. Пишите на том языке, на котором лучше пишете, после реализации в случае возникновения проблем вы легко сможете переписать на другом языке/приделать костыли в оригинальном